# Visual Studio Code: The SUID sandbox helper binary was found

Tags: command-line, upgrade, xfce, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code in Ubuntu 20.04 using apt-get install code. It is showing on the applications list, but it is not starting if I click on it. Also on the terminal it's not starting using code.

However i ran `code --verbose` and produced the following output

> 8431:0922/005249.057050:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /usr/share/code/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you confirmed that the file in the error message is owned by `root` and has the correct permissions?

Comment: yes it a;so has read and write permissions